# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i do a click event, the setState can not work in a fetch.

```
buttonClick = (event) => {
  let category = event.target.id;
  let url = this.state.urls[category];
  this.setState = ({
    planets: [],
    starships: [],
    vehicles: [],
    people: [],
    films: []
  });    
  fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())       
    .then(
      data => this.setState({ category: data })  //error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.setState is not a function
    );
};
```

hope to fix this error

Comment: Cool. Without a [mcve] though, there's literally nothing we can tell you: `this` inside an arrow function is derived from the execution context that _declares_ rather than _executes_ the arrow function, so you'll have to show that larger context.

Comment: How did u call buttonClick method ? Please write the source code

Answer (score 1):

> Problem

The problem here is that you've overridden the `setState` from `function` to an `object`.

When you write

```
    this.setState = ({
        planets: [],
        starships: [],
        vehicles: [],
        people: [],
        films: []
      });
```

then `this.setState` is not a function anymore, and later you trying to call it, so the error is expected, this.setState is not a function.

---

> Solution

All you have to do is instead of assigning data to the `setState` just pass the data in the function call like

```
  this.setState({
       planets: [],
       starships: [],
       vehicles: [],
       people: [],
       films: []
     });
```

Your call of `setState` in `then` of `fetch` will work then

Comment: Hello, if this is the solution for your answer, you can mark it as the accepted answer so that other visitors to your question can directly go for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.setState({planets: [],
    starships: [],
    vehicles: [],
    people: [],
    films: []
})
```

Comment: Try to add a little explanation along with the code.